# How to get delimiters after split by multiple delimiters?

Tags: regex, string, flutter, split

I use this `phones = value.split(RegExp(r":| |：|　|）"));` to split my phone numbers, so I got `内線`, `7+90+21931465` and `070-2193-1465` from `内線：7+90+21931465:070-2193-1465`, but I want to show them as 内線：*7+90+21931465*:*070-2193-1465*, how can I get array as `内線`, `：`, `7+90+21931465`, `:` and `070-2193-1465`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var value = '内線：7+90+21931465:070-2193-1465';
  var regExp = RegExp(r'^(.+)(：|:)(.+)(：|:)(.+)$');

  print(value);
  var match = regExp.firstMatch(value);
  var numGroups = match.groupCount;
  var groups = match.groups(List<int>.generate(numGroups, (i) => i + 1));
  print(groups.toString());
```

Another way:

```
  var chesu = value.split(RegExp(r'：|:'))..insert(1, '：')..insert(3, ':');
  print(chesu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```dart
void main() {
  final input = "part1:part2;part3%part4";
  
  final result = <String>[];
  
  input.splitMapJoin(
    RegExp(r":|;|%"), 
    onMatch: (match) {
      result.add(match.group(0));
      return "";
    },
    onNonMatch: (value) {
      result.add(value);
      return "";
    },
  );
  
  print(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[part1, :, part2, ;, part3, %, part4]
```